# MVC3 Editing Grid AJAX feature shows strange behaviour

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

I am facing a problem with AjaxForm. This is a lengthy description and I have spent a lot of time on it already so wanted some ideas.

I have a grid displaying Phone(or other) details . I am trying to ajax edit a grid using a Edit Div immediately above the grid.When the edit is saved I am refreshing the entire grid div.
See below

```
   <div class="boxBody AccordionDetails" style="width: 980px; padding: 10px;">
        <div id="@Constants.AjaxPhoneResult" title="Phone Numbers">
    </div>
    <div id="@Constants.AjaxPhoneEditListResult">
            @Html.Partial("_PhoneListEdit", @Model)
      </div>
```

The grid is returned as HTML table by the partial "_PhoneListEdit". Each line has an Ajax Action Link rendering the following partial into the above AjaxPhoneResult Div- see below

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(action,
   new AjaxOptions
        {
            UpdateTargetId = Constants.AjaxPhoneEditListResult,
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            HttpMethod = "POST"
        }
            ))
{ 
       @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ContactID)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PhoneNum)
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNum)
        <input id="PhoneSubmit" type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

The above Ajax Form renders correctly as I can observe using FireBug. However when I press Save the results(Json partial view string) displays in a new form rather than replacing the contents of the grid with updated data.Also I am sure that I have included the JQuery ajax js scripts,The interesting thing is that if I display the AJAX form in a Popup window using JQuery Dialog , the Ajax form works correctly although the markup generated is same.

I am wondering if some action needs to be performed on the AJAX form elements at form load? Maybe that is performed when you use a Jquery dialog. Any help would be appreciated.